# onActivityResult not called after click the button (using Google Drive API)

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I use the following link to use the Google Drive API to upload a file to Drive:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rznYp43KLRc

When I call requestSignIn() in onCreate, it works correctly. But when I call it in setOnClickListener, it doesn't work!

My code looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // When I call requestSignIn here it works correctly 
    // requestSignIn();
}

private void requestSignIn() {
    GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
            .build();
    GoogleSignInClient client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,signInOptions);
    startActivityForResult(client.getSignInIntent(), 400);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 400:
            if(resultCode== RESULT_OK)
            {
                handleSignInIntent(data);
            }
    }
}

private void handleSignInIntent(Intent data) {
    GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount) {
                    GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential
                            .usingOAuth2(MainActivity.this , Collections.singleton(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE));

                    credential.setSelectedAccount(googleSignInAccount.getAccount());

                    Drive googleDriveService= new Drive.Builder(
                            AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                            new GsonFactory(),
                            credential)
                            .setApplicationName("My Drive Totorial")
                            .build();
                    driveServiceHelper = new DriveServiceHelper(googleDriveService);



                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                }
            });
}


btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            
            if (signatureView.isBitmapEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bitte unterschreiben", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                
                // I want to sign in to Google Drive now 
                 requestSignIn(); // but it doesn't work!
            }
        }
    });
```

What I want is that "Sign in to client" should not be possible while the "activity is loading", but it should only be possible after "submit" has been clicked.

When I debug the code, requestSignIn() is being called correctly, but onActivityResult is not called correctly.

In my code below, after doing

`startActivityForResult(client.getSignInIntent(), 400)`

it never reaches onActivityResult.

I am a beginner with Android. I don't underestand where is the problem? Do you have any idea?!

Thanks in advance

++++UPDATE 18.04.2023+++

in the mainActivity worked the program without any Problemm as intended

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button btnSubmit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.submit);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            requestSignIn(); //it works correctly
        }
    });
}
private void requestSignIn() {
    GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
            .build();
    GoogleSignInClient client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,signInOptions);
    startActivityForResult(client.getSignInIntent(), 400);
    // I see ++++startActivityForResult+++
    Toast.makeText(this, " ++++startActivityForResult+++", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // I see +++++++++++onActivityResult+++++++++
    Toast.makeText(this, "+++++++++++onActivityResult+++++++++ ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 400:
            if(resultCode== RESULT_OK)
            {
                handleSignInIntent(data);
            }
    }
}
```

when I take the same Code to SecondActivity, it doesn't work.

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button btnSubmit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.submit);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            requestSignIn(); // it doesn't work!!!!
        }
    });
}
private void requestSignIn() {
    GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(new Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE))
            .build();
    GoogleSignInClient client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,signInOptions);
    startActivityForResult(client.getSignInIntent(), 400);
    // I see ++startActivityForResult++
    Toast.makeText(this, " ++startActivityForResult++", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // But here that shows no ++++++++++onActivityResult+++++++++
    Toast.makeText(this, "+++++++++++onActivityResult+++++++++ ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 400:
            if(resultCode== RESULT_OK)
            {
                handleSignInIntent(data);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `btnSubmit.setOnClickListener` actually inside `onCreate` in your code? Can you include more details about how you debugged it and what the result was? For example, does it launch the sign in activity when you click the button? Were you using log statements to determine which methods were called?

Comment: @TylerV No, btnSubmit.setOnClickListener is not inside onCreate in my code. 
I have use log statment in both method. requestSignIn() called but onActivityResult is not called.

Comment: Where is it then? Usually that kind of code goes in `onCreate`. Is the sign in activity launched? If not, check logcat for any error messages.

Comment: @TylerV Now I have put btnSubmit.setOnClickListener in OnCreate, but it still doesn't work!

Comment: Update the question to show the updated code please. Can you replicate it in a minimal app in a new project?

Comment: @TylerV I have checked the code in different Activity. Once I wrote the code in the mainActivity and the program worked without any Problemm as intended (requestSignIn() is called exactly when the btnSubmit.setOnClickListener and onActivityresult also worked.). But, when I take the same program to another activity, it doesn't work. I'm really confused and I don't understand why this is happening. (The question has been updated)

Comment: Am I correct in assuming in `SecondActivity` you see the `requestSignIn` toast but not the `onActivityResult` toast, while in `MainActivity` you see both? Try to use specific statements in your question instead of "It doesn't work". As-is I don't see anything wrong with the code that would cause the behavior you are describing. Is the "Sign In" activity displayed in SecondActivity?

Comment: @TylerV yes sir. you are correct . I have update my question . I don't understand where my problem is. same code in two different activities! in mainactivity works correctly and called onActivityResult but in second activity it never reaches onActivityResult.